# Encrypting DB with multi user access

Tags: encryption, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric

I am working on a project that will be sold to government entities. Because they will be storing sensitive lists of employees, they do not want us to have access to their DB.

I am not an encryption specialist, but I was thinking of encrypting the DB the app uses in such a way that we do not have access to it, but many users in their organisation (users they gave permissions to) must be able to read the data from their app.

How does that work? I read about public/private keys, symmetric/asymmetric encryption, but I'm having a hard time understanding how all of that fits in.

Comment: The common practice is to externalize the DB credentials to some configuration file, and for the developer to have the credentials to the development and test DB, but not the production DB.

Comment: @jingx I'm assuming the file system needs to be encrypted as well if we're going to save those keys in a config file?

Comment: And what about the user (iOS, android, web) going to read and write the data?

Comment: Not necessarily. There are many ways and combinations of them to lock down a production environment. E.g. make the config file only readable by the authorized user(s). File system level encryption is useful but for some entirely unrelated purposes (e.g. prevent the security breach after a physical theft)

Comment: Well if the user is accessing the data in due course of using the application, then it's up to your in-app security system to control the access, isn't it? Encrypting everything hardly protects anything from the users coming through the front door.

Comment: Agreed, I mean how do you encrypt so that multiple users can then decrypt to consume the data. Isn't there a public/private key logic required?

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is you don't need to encrypt the entire DB, but if you must encrypt the data in a way that can be deciphered by multiple users, I imagine it would be done in the good old share-the-master-key theme.